# Regular expression, allow 0 to 3 uppercase letters

Tags: regex, expression, uppercase

I need RegExp for username input to allow maximum 3 capital letters.

> asdFasdFasdF - pass
>
> FFFasd       - pass
>
> asdFFF       - pass
>
> aFFsdF       - pass
>
> asd          - pass
>
> FFFF         - fail
>
> asdFadsFFF   - fail

You get what I want.

Please help as I am stuck with this for a long time.

I tried this `(?=(.*?[A-Z]){0,3})` but fails and maybe I don't need lookahead.

Comment: Consider that such rule makes little to no sense as soon as you leave the small range of ascii characters, so as soon as you go international.

Comment: I don't want user to have more than 3 capital letters.

Comment: The concept of "capital letters" does make little sense in a unicode alphabeth. It only makes sense in asci and some iso encodings, so in "classical" western languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ASCII only, try this:

```
^([^A-Z]*[A-Z]?[^A-Z]*){0,3}$
```

For Unicode uppercase, try this:

```
^([^\p{Lu}]*\p{Lu}?[^\p{Lu}]*){0,3}$
```

Comment: @bmbl87, forgot the `?` after the uppercase pattern. I added them.

Answer (score 1):

Use an anchored negative look ahead:

```
^(?!(.*?[A-Z]){4}).*$
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/LKGwEa747E)

Comment: this is brilliant! At least imho. There is a small typo though 3 should really be 4. 3 capital letters is valid.